# ggplot2 does not show the graph in Latex (knitr)

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex, knitr

I have an issue with knitr and ggplot2 in Latex. I am trying to create a dynamic document with knitr. All my plots are in ggplot2. Hear me out:

1. I created the Latex document
2. I opened it in R Studio and saved the TEX file as RNW file. Global and Project options: knitr.
3. I pasted the R script there like:

```
<<echo=FALSE>>=
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path='graphs/',
                      echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE)
@

<<>>=
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
@

<<plot1>>=
my_data1 <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=TRUE, sep=",")

plot1 <- ggplot(data=my_data1, aes(x = pos , y = sum)) +
  geom_line(colour = 'black', size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = 'log10', limits = c(1,100)) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs (x = 'axis_name1', y = 'axis_name2') +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(1219890,1220102)) +
@
```

Everything is going well, except the graph does not show when I press 'Compile PDF' or in the graphs directory. However when I select only the R code and run it everything is fine(as long as I add print()). I managed to use TikZ which works just fine but without creating a dynamic document. I thought it was possible to output the plot directly in the PDF document but for some reason ggplot2 does not work. Is there something that I am missing?

Thank you.

Comment: When pasting your code into a standard RMD document I got two issues. At the end of the last line of your plot code there is is an additonal `+` which raises an unexpected end of input error when knitting. Second. When you are creating the plot your are only saving it as plot1. To print the plot add a line `plot1` or `print(plot1)` to your code.

Comment: The `+` sign was an unfortunate mistake when I wrote the post. Thank you for that. I tried adding `print()` and I got the error **Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y :** I tried searching on internet but I could not find anything that applies to my problem.